# how to access information in a file? C++

Tags: c++, struct, iostream, binaryfiles, records

Im having trouble with 2 things, first in my if statement for choice C it should take the selected record from the file and change its contents, but it does not work for some reason the file contents do not change. Also in choice D i need it to be able to read the and add all the quantities and sales costs from the file and add them together then display them. Im not even sure where to start with this one. I know I need to access the info from the file, but only the lines with thus said data, then add them together and save them in a variable to be displayed, but how can I access only the lines in the file that have that data?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    using namespace std;

    struct Info
    {
        // create inventory items info
        string ItemDescription;
        int Quantity;
        double WholesaleCost;
        double RetailCost;
        string Date;
    };

    int main()
    {
        //make instance of info and a variable for user selection
        Info Item;
        char choice;
        // set up functions
        long byteNum(int);
        void showRec(Info);
        void changeRec(Info);
        //open file
        fstream inventory("inventory.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
        // loop for user selection
        do
        {
            cout << "press 'A' to add files\n";
            cout << "press 'D' to display files\n";
            cout << "press 'C' to Change files\n";
            cout << "press 'G' to Generate a record\n";
            cout << "or press 'Q' to quit\n";
            cin >> choice;
            //if add files get record info put it into struct and save it tofile
            if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
            {

                cout << "enter Item description\n";
                cin >> Item.ItemDescription;
                cout << "enter quantity on hand\n";
                cin >> Item.Quantity;
                cout << "enter whole sale cost\n";
                cin >> Item.WholesaleCost;
                cout << "enter Item retail cost\n";
                cin >> Item.RetailCost;
                cout << "enter date added to inventory\n";
                cin >> Item.Date;
                cout << "data added\n";
                inventory.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item), sizeof(Item));

            }
            //display record
            else if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
            {
                int recordChoice;
                // get which record user wants
                cout << "enter which record number you want?";
                cin >> recordChoice;
                // display record info
                cout << " here is record " << recordChoice << endl;
                inventory.seekg(byteNum(recordChoice), ios::beg);
                inventory.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item), sizeof(Item));
                showRec(Item);

            }
            // change record info
            else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
            {
                int recordChoice;
                //get which record user wants to change
                cout << "enter which record number you want to change?";
                cin >> recordChoice;
                // change struct info and save it over old record in the file
                changeRec(Item);
                inventory.seekp(byteNum(recordChoice), ios::beg);
                inventory.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item), sizeof(Item));

            }
            else if (choice == 'G' || choice == 'g')
            {


                cout << "D";
            }



        } while (choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q');


        inventory.close();
        return 0;
    }

    long byteNum(int recNum)
    {
        // get record selection number
        return sizeof(Info) * recNum;
    }

    void showRec(Info record)
    {
        // display record info
        cout << record.ItemDescription << endl;
        cout << record.Quantity << endl;
        cout << record.WholesaleCost << endl;
        cout << record.RetailCost << endl;
        cout << record.Date << endl;
    }

    void changeRec(Info record)
    {
        // change record info in struct
        cout << "enter new Item description\n";
        cin >> record.ItemDescription;
        cout << "enter new quantity on hand\n";
        cin >> record.Quantity;
        cout << "enter new whole sale cost\n";
        cin >> record.WholesaleCost;
        cout << "enter new Item retail cost\n";
        cin >> record.RetailCost;
        cout << "enter new date added to inventory\n";
        cin >> record.Date;
        cout << "data added\n";
    }
```

Comment: You cannot have `std::string` members being trivially de-/serialized from/into binary files.

Comment: Please read up on `std::tolower` and `std::toupper` so you can reduce the number of comparisons (or better yet, the number of `case`s in a `switch` statement).

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ serialization technique string".  The input and output of classes to a file is called *serialization*.  There are many articles describing how to handle data types that contain pointers such as `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Your class consists of a bunch of `std::string`s (and a few other things, but that's not important).

A `std::string` is a class that implements a text string-like interface. It is not a string itself. Typically, a `std::string` consists of a pointer to a heap-allocated buffer, the size of the string, and perhaps some other metadata.

You don't have to worry about any of that. All you have to do is access `std::string` methods, like `substr()`, and others, and you get the result. The class itself manages its internal metadata, and is responsible for it. You call `substr()`, the class uses its internal pointer to find the requested parts of the string, and returns it, and so on.

```
inventory.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item), sizeof(Item));
```

So, you end up writing the binary contents of your `Item` structure to a file. Which includes a bunch of `std::string`s. That's great. Your file contains now has some binary data which that includes raw memory addresses of a bunch of heap-allocated buffers that contain the text strings. It does not contain the text strings themselves.

When you read them back later, all you'll get would be the same raw memory addresses. Which is great, except that, now, it's a completely different process, and raw memory addresses used by some process that terminated some time ago is ...not very useful. And when you try to access them, your code blows up, because all those pointers are now meaningless nonsense.

Ask yourself the following simple question: you understand that you wrote `sizeof(Item)` bytes, in that `write`() call, above, right? And you know that `sizeof(Item)` is a constant expression (or, at least, one of the first things your instructor in your C++ class should've told you is that `sizeof` is always a constant expression). So, the question you need to ask yourself how is it possible to always write some constant number of bytes, whether or not one of the strings in the `Item` structure contains ten characters, or ten thousand characters?

Unfortunately, this is not as simple as a just a `write`() and `read`() calls. You need to come up with a file format that represents the contents of your `Item` class, and implement distinct methods to write the contents of all fields, one by one, to the file, and read it back.

The comments to your question already gave you some Google food. Use it.

Comment: ok ty, Ill look up serialization and see if i can find a way to reformat my file.